# "PIP is in the PYTHONPATH. Please change directory so it is not."

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy

I am working on Windows. I installed mypy and added it to external tools.
When I launch the tool, I get this message:

```
C:\Users\MediaMonster\anaconda3\envs\APIP\Scripts\mypy.exe Downloads\bad_code.py
C:\Users\MediaMonster\anaconda3\envs\APIP is in the PYTHONPATH. Please change directory so it is not.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you help me fix this problem?

I also enclosed the settings for the external tool.

[image: ToolParameter]

Answer (score 0):

Your [PYTHONPATH](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythonpath-environment-variable-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20PYTHONPATH%20variable%20holds%20a,are%20not%20made%20installable%20yet.) stores important file paths for your Python system.

For some reason, MyPy doesn't want APIP in the path. You need to figure out how to remove APIP from the path, typically through your Windows user settings or from the command line. Some potential [tips](https://quick-adviser.com/how-do-i-remove-something-from-a-python-path/#How_do_I_remove_something_from_a_Python_path).

Hope this helps. LMK